# What does the | in |Z| mean in mathematical expressions for distribution statistics

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, notation

I am doing some self study on statistics and noticed that in the notes that I was using the $|Z|$ expression as attached in the photos below. I am confused with the "$|$" that is being used. The only logical conclusion that I was able to draw was that $P(|Z|\le 2)$ represents $P(-2 < Z < 2)$.

I would appreciate some advice on what the "$|$" symbol means.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the absolute value. So |-5| = 5, and |5| = 5.

$$ P( |Z| \leq 2) = P( Z \leq 2\text{  and}-Z \leq 2) = P(Z \leq 2\text{ and }Z \geq -2) = P(-2 \leq Z \leq 2) = P(Z \geq -2) - P(Z \geq 2) = 1 - H(2) - H(2)$$

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the speedy reply. I am curious also why when we have the | symbol in place, we are looking at a two-tail in our calculation? Thank you so much once again. =)

Comment: By defining the p-value using absolute values you don't need 2 defnitinos for 2-tails and 1-tail tests, but rather 1 equation will suffice.

Comment: that's another way of saying that the distribution shown in the plot is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. The explanation had been lucid, I now understand the concept. Appreciate it lots.